# Understanding ({var}) notation and arrow function React Native

Tags: react-native, ecmascript-6

I'm new to React Native and ES6, but know a little about JS and I'm having difficulty finding out what the following code means. I know what it does and I can identify bits of it, but not everything.

```
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    if (navigation.state.params == undefined )
    {
      return {
        headerTitle: <Text></Text>,
        headerLeft: null
      }
    }
    else
    {
      return {
        headerTitle: navigation.state.params.toolbarComponent,
        headerLeft: null
      };
    }
  };
```

Now I know about the arrow function, that's fine, but I'm really confused about where the navigation variable is coming from. If I remove the braces so the first line looks like this:

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
```

Then the code complains about prop not existing, so I assume this uses a bind on navigation.

So really what I can't work out is where navigation is coming from, i.e. in another example somewhere else how will I know what the variable name is called. And if you can confirm what the braces do around the variable navigation then  I would appreciate it. I suspect this is really an ES6 question.

Comment: Why don't you just run the code through babel and look at the output? It's a lot easier than googling for syntax.

Comment: Because I'm an Android/Java developer and I'm starting to port my app to React, and I didn't know what was a thing... thanks I'll have a go at that. Much appreciated.

Comment: Yup. They have an [online compiler](https://babeljs.io/repl/) you can use to look at small stuff without going through the rigamarole of a build process or CLI tools.

Comment: Great, thanks again. I did start trying to install the CLI, but saw your comment before actually trying to use it. Lots of learning to do for me I think.

Comment: No worries. You may come to appreciate JavaScript's syntactic shortcuts vs. Java's regularity once you get used to them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
```

^ this is destructuring assignment.  So for example you call `navigationOptions` function with object argument something like

```
navigationOptions({navigation:navigation, somethingElse: somethingElse})
```

then it will pick navigation from passed object.

Read more about destructuring here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Here is another good post about this http://wesbos.com/destructuring-objects/

Also check [Destructuring objects as function parameters in ES6](https://simonsmith.io/destructuring-objects-as-function-parameters-in-es6/)

Comment: It would be like to access to the 'navigation' attribute of the passed object don't?

Comment: Thanks for that. Really helpful, having what it is named is half the battle, however after reading about it I suspect I have some really basic misunderstanding of what's going on.

So destructuring is pulling data from a more complex object so:

    let {a}={a:1,b:2};

Means that a=1. I don't see where the right side of the static assignment is pulling an object that contains navigationOptions..

Of course there's where you can use destructuring with a function, but navigationOptions doesn't appear to exist in the class before hand, nor do I know where the navigation comes from.

Comment: @RichShepard `navigationOptions` is a class method of whatever class (you omitted it in the code provided, I'm assuming its a React component), and it expects to be passed an object that has a `navigation` property as a parameter, which it then destructures into a local variable of the same name.

Comment: Also keep in mind in Javascript you don't need to declare variable like in Java and other languages.  In JS if you do x=1 then variable x is declared automatically.

Comment: so if the navigation property is there in passed object then it will be assigned other it will be undefined.

Comment: @Abhishek Yeah I was aware of the declaration differences between JS and Java. I suspect though I'm thinking too much in Java.

Comment: @JaredSmith Yes it's a react component, I think my possibly flawed logic was that I could output the method by something like console.log(MyClass.navigationOptions) or console.log (this.navigationOptions), which I can't until I set it. Both of those output as undefined until I add the statement my initial question. Perhaps reading more of the reactNavigation project might help me.

Comment: @RichShepard you can indeed output the method by writing `console.log(MyClass.navigationOptions)`, however make sure to put it outside of the class definition.

Comment: @JaredSmith That explains it. Thanks once again.